# Parse.com Android public void done does not return my ArrayList properly

Tags: android

I want to fill an ArrayList with the results I get back from a Parse query. When I get the results I add them to the ArrayList and print the ArrayList size to the console to make sure the results are added, which is succesful, but when I return the ArrayList it's empty. Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

```
public ArrayList<ParseObject>findAllGroupByUserId(ParseUser userId){
    //TODO hier uit db halen alle groupen van user
    final ArrayList<ParseObject> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    ParseQuery<Group_user> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group_user");
    query.whereEqualTo("user_id", userId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Group_user>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Group_user> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (Group_user group : objects) {
                    Log.e("SUCCESS", group.getObjectId() + " , " + group.getGroup_id().getObjectId());
                    ParseObject g = new Group();
                    groups.add(g);

                }
                System.out.println(groups.size() + " :Done method"); //THIS RETURNS 2
            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR", "message: " + e);
            }
            Log.e("SUCCESS", "we have " + groups.size() + " results");
        }
    });
    System.out.println(groups.size() + " :return"); // THIS RETURNS 0
    return groups;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `findInBackground()` runs asynchronously on a different thread. You need to execute your remaining logic from the `done()` call back to get the populated array.

Think of it like this:

Thread 1 -> invokes findInBackground() -> thread one is running -----------> group is empty until Thread 2 finishes

Thread 2 spawned -> reaches out to server and gets query results -> invokes done call back on Thread 1 (now you have the data ready)

Comment: So where do I have to put the return statement in the done() callback? I can't change the done method to an ArrayList because it's an overriding method.

Comment: Yes you cannot return from it so you would need to populate or do what ever needs to be done after the data is fetched.  You can do something like populateViews(groups) and then just invoke it from the done() method. Where populateViews() maps your data with your views

Comment: So does it even make sense to have my findAllGroupsByUserId method return something?

Comment: No it does not as it is right now you do not need to return anything

Comment: So I want to display the results in a spinner in an activity somwhere else. What would be the best way to get the results to that activity?

Comment: Well there are multiple ways.  Here are couple: You can just move your query logic in that activity OR  You can pass the data to that activity (in which case your data will need to be serializable or parcelable)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming that Group_user is a subclass of ParseObject that you've already defined. Since the findInBackground is async, you should change logic of the calling of the function to async too. Instead of returning list of objects like you were before, do all the logic in the done function of the query, no need to return.

```
public void findAllGroupByUserId(ParseUser userId) {
    ParseQuery<Group_user> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group_user");
    query.whereEqualTo("user_id", userId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Group_user>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Group_user> groups, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null && groups != null) {
                for (Group_user group : groups) {
                    // perform all logic here
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Find Callback", "Oh no! Query failed!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```